# bash. regexp using bash_rematch

Tags: regex, bash

I have a var which can has single quotes or spaces before and/or after:

```
var="' /path/to/somewhere '"
var=" /path/to/somewhere "#<- here is a space at the end
var="/path/to/somewhere'"
var=" /path/to/somewhere '"
```

I need a regexp using bash rematch to clean possible single quotes or blank spaces before and after

I know it can be done in this way:

```
var=${var##+([ \'])}
var=${var%%+([ \'])}
```

But I need it with BASH_REMATCH (long to explain xd). I'm trying with:

```
[[ ${var} =~ ^([\' ]*)?(.+)([\' ])?$ ]] && var="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

But it doesn't work. Probably .+ is getting the rest of the string. How can I get only the interesting part? Thanks.

Comment: yes sorry... I'll edit the post. all has double quotes... sorry.

Comment: If your use of regex is long to explain, maybe it's not a good reason after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.+` in your example is what's causing the problem, as it is greedy, so it will consume the rest of the line.

In this case, you can prevent it from doing so by requiring that the part in the middle ends in something other than a space or `'`, like this:

```
re='^[ '"'"']*(.*[^ '"'"'])[ '"'"']*$'
[[ $var =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

The nasty-looking `'"'"'` are needed to insert a literal `'` into a single-quoted string. When working with regular expressions in bash, the recommended method is to define a variable containing the pattern in single quotes and then to use it, unquoted (this method works in all versions of bash that support regular expressions).

Comment: Maybe `re='^[ '"'"']*(.*[^ '"'"'])[ '"'"']*$'`. Otherwise you'll have problems with, e.g., `var="'x'"`.

Comment: Can you explain why a lazy modifier like '?' wouldn't work?

Comment: @TylerMassey as far as I'm aware, Bash Regular Expressions don't support the lazy modifier.